# Bare Json response of a WCF service in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf, jquery

I have made a WCF service in .NET 4 platform, that when I hit it with a jquery ajax POST it returns JSON.
The issue that I have is that I would prefer if the json response of the POST is not wrapped in the name of the Method with the Result suffix.

In detail:

```
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Person GetInfo(string id);
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode
    = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service: Iservice
{
    public Person GetInfo(string id)
    {
           ...
           return new Person();
    }
}

public class Person
{
  public string FirstName;
  public string LastName;

  public Person(){
   FirstName = "Jon";
   LastName = "Doe";
  }
}

web.config
<system.serviceModel>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
   <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
       </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
     <endpointBehaviors>
       <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
         <webHttp/>
       </behavior>
     </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <services>
     <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
       <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
           contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
     </service>
   </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

jquery:

```
var myparameters = JSON.stringify({ id: $('#id').val()});
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Service.svc/GetInfo",
                data:myparameters,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                      ...
                    }
                }
            });
```

With the `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped` the response a get in my javascript code is:

```
{"GetInfoResult" : {"FirstName":"Jon", "LastName":"Doe"}}
```

But when I change it to `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` and everything else remains the same, a 500 internal server error occurs.

Is it possible to return Bare json in my POST response without the Method+Result wrapper? If yes what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` expects also a "bare" request, and you are sending an object from your javascript code, something like this : `{id:'value'}`  that will be translated as :

```
public class DTObject{
  public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

And your operation method expects only a `string` as parameter.

Try to make only your response "bare" like this `WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest`.

**[Edit]** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webmessagebodystyle.aspx